# External C# program cannot invoke vsto COMAddin object method, but it can inside debugger

Tags: c#, dynamic, com, vsto, office-interop

I have these simple code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            object addInName = "MyAddin";
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Core.COMAddIn addin = app.COMAddIns.Item(ref addInName); 

            app.Visible = false;
            var myObject = addin.Object;
            var vvv = myObject.someMethod();
        }
```

When run it, it fails on line **someMethod** throwing NullReferenceException. But myObject is not null.

If I put a breakpoint on that line, move over mouse cursor to myObject, click the expending **Dynamic View** and click some **Interface View**. Then it works!

It seems that the COM object, although is not null, is not ready/initialized yet. But if I check it's internal state from debugger breakpoint, somehow i force it to initialize.

What is the problem?

the Addin COM extends the StandardOleMarshalObject alrady.

Comment: Have you seen the information in this MSDN article: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608621.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try using the late-binding technology (Reflection in .Net). See [Type.InvokeMember](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.invokemember%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for more information.

Are both applications run in the same security context? Or do you run any of them with admin privileges (run as admin)?

Comment: This answer looks more like a comment.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11161902)

Comment: I suggested to use the late-binding technology which might help. In most cases it helps to avoid such issues.